# Eclipse complaining of missing Junit jar even though it is already in build path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I have the below Maven/Eclipse setup and I have already added junit as a compile time dependency in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone clarify why I am being prompted by Eclipse to add junit to build path?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: You should add <scope>test</scope>

Comment: No change after adding junit to test scope.

Comment: Verified md5 hash of junit-3.8.2.jar in my local maven repository is correct. Is this some kind of bug in eclipse?

Comment: Did you try running a clean build?

Comment: Right-click the project and select "Maven > Update Project..."

Comment: Does it work if you do mvn clean test from the command line?

Comment: Clean/build/Update project nothing worked. Upgrading junit version to 4.12 worked however...

Comment: You are using Junit 4 annotation with Junit 3 jar file

Comment: Thanks, looks like annotations are not supported in Junit 3

Comment: Annotations support is the major feature of JUnit 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need JUnit 4 if you want to use annotations.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like support for annotations was added in Junit4.

Answer (score 0):

Do following:

1. Update maven project.
2. Clean your project.

And then re run your test